# Predicting Dance Frames with Pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, lstm, autoencoder

I created  a VAE archictecture to encode dance frames into latent representations.

Then I planned to use LSTM to take a sequence of those latent vectors to predict the next one. Then decode it and thus generate a new dance sequence.

However, this is not working. The LSTMs prediction is slightly off which makes the predicted frame not entirely accurate. Since that inaccurate frame is used as input to the LSTM next, the prediction of the LSTM becomes even worse off until the predictions are just black.

Does anyone have experience with encoded sequential data prediction who knows how to solve the issue? Or maybe could suggest another architecture that can work to predict dance frames?

Comment: You should take a look at scheduled sampling, which can help you reduce these inacuracies https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.03099